# How to disable DIAB compiler optimization locally within a source file?

Tags: optimization

I use windriver, diab and we have project level compiler optimization settings. There is some piece of code for which I need to disable optimization.

I tried #pragma option -g0 , but it did not work.

Can someone suggest how to do it in diab?

Thanks a lot,
-Varun